# how to using MySQL pattern matching and binding parameters in sql query in python?

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I know how to use MySQL pattern matching, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%mid%'
```

I also know how to bind parameters into a sql query in python, for example:

```
import MySQLdb
s = 'something'
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=blablabla...)
cur = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = %s"
cur.execute(sql, s)
data = cur.fetchall()
db.close()
```

But I can't find a method to combine these together in one query, like

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%%s%'"
cur.execute(sql, s)
```

where the first and the third '%' are pattern character and the middle '%s' is used to bind parameter s.
Anyone have an idea?

Comment: `sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = %s" %some_words` before call..

Comment: @dsgdfg oh yes, that works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @XiangZhang: But **don't use that** because it's vulnerable to SQL injection!

Comment: @Eric Yes, I realized that. Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I will answer myself..
@dsgdfg inspired me and here is my code:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE %s"
cur.execute(sql, "%"+s+"%")
```

Comment: This is better than @dsgdfg's answer because you're leaving the interpolation to the database driver, which should protect you from injection

Comment: Yes, but still looking for better solution. I think this method is not that beautiful

Comment: Thnx for warning. deleted answer  @Eric

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE CONCAT('%', %s, '%')"
cur.execute(sql, s)
```

(I am assuming that `execute` deals with escaping, thereby preventing SQL injection.)

Answer (score 0):

for the people using py charm
you can do this

```
qq=input("enter the author name:")
print(pd.read_sql_query("select Book_Id,Book_Name,book_author from bookd where book_author like '%s'" %("%"+qq+"%",), conn2))
```

[image]